# where is hadoop-test.jar in Hadoop2?

Tags: hadoop, benchmarking, hadoop2

I want to use `testmapredsort` for benchmarking sort in Hadoop. I am NOT using TeraSort now.

`hadoop-*test*.jar` is supposed to contain the `testmapredsort` class. But I do not see `hadoop-*test*.jar` in `Hadoop2`.

```
hadoop jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0-tests.jar testmapredsort /data/unsorted-data -sortOutput /data/sorted-data
```

Comment: can't you just search for it?

Comment: @zhutoulala: I searched and could not locate it. let me know if you can locate it by search.However answer by Dennis below is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hadoop 1, `testmapredsort` is launched from `AllTestDriver.java`, which was indeed in e.g. `hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar`. In Hadoop 2, it's now in MapredTestDriver.java, which can be found inside of `hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar`

```
hadoop jar hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar testmapredsort -sortInput /data/unsorted-data -sortOutput /data/sorted-data
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. but I have another problem with I have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369721/error-during-benchmarking-sort-in-hadoop2-partitions-do-not-match