# Error during benchmarking Sort in Hadoop2 - Partitions do not match

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, benchmarking, hadoop2

I am trying to benchmark Hadoop2 MapReduce framework. It is NOT TeraSort. But `testmapredsort`.

**step-1** 
Create random data:

```
hadoop jar hadoop/ randomwriter -Dtest.randomwrite.bytes_per_map=100 -Dtest.randomwriter.maps_per_host=10 /data/unsorted-data
```

**step-2** sort the random data created in step-1:

```
hadoop jar hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar sort /data/unsorted-data /data/sorted-data
```

**step-3** check if the sorting by `MR` works:

```
hadoop jar hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar testmapredsort -sortInput /data/unsorted-data -sortOutput /data/sorted-data
```

I get the following error during step-3. I want to know how to fix this this error.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Partitions do not match for record# 0 ! - '0' v/s '5'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Partitions do not match for record# 0 ! - '0' v/s '5'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SortValidator$RecordStatsChecker$Map.map(SortValidator.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SortValidator$RecordStatsChecker$Map.map(SortValidator.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
14/08/18 11:07:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local2061890210_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
14/08/18 11:07:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 23
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=1436271
        FILE: Number of bytes written=1645526
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=1077294840
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=13
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=1
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=102247
        Map output records=102247
        Map output bytes=1328251
        Map output materialized bytes=26
        Input split bytes=102
        Combine input records=102247
        Combine output records=1
        Spilled Records=1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=22
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=198766592
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=1077294840
java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SortValidator$RecordStatsChecker.checkRecords(SortValidator.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SortValidator.run(SortValidator.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SortValidator.main(SortValidator.java:594)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.run(MapredTestDriver.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.main(MapredTestDriver.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

**EDIT**:

```
hadoop fs -ls /data/unsorted-data
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup          0 2014-08-14 12:45 /data/unsorted-data/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup 1077294840 2014-08-14 12:45 /data/unsorted-data/part-m-00000

hadoop fs -ls /data/sorted-data
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup          0 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  137763270 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134220478 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00001
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134219656 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00002
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134218029 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00003
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134219244 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00004
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134220252 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00005
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134224231 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00006
-rw-r--r--   3 david supergroup  134210232 2014-08-14 12:55 /data/sorted-data/part-m-00007
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the sorting in step-2 at least produced reasonable output? What's the output of `hdfs dfs -ls /data/unsorted-data` and `hdfs dfs -ls /data/sorted-data`?

Comment: @DennisHuo:see my edit above: both produced reasonable outputs

Comment: Do you have the actual command you used for the initial `randomwriter` job as well as the beginning of the console output? It's a bit strange to have a single 1GB output from `randomwriter`, though in part it's because while Hadoop 1 uses `test.randomwrite.bytes_per_map` and `test.randomwriter.maps_per_host`, Hadoop 2 uses the keys  `mapreduce.randomwriter.bytespermap` and `mapreduce.randomwriter.mapsperhost`, as seen in [RandomWriter.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RandomWriter.java).

Comment: @DennisHuo: can you please elaborate what you mean here? your solution  below worked. if you can explain what you mean in the comment above, it will be very helpful

Comment: Ah, I was just trying to replicate your configuration to reproduce the issue, and no matter what I tried I always ended up with multiple 1GB files after running randomwriter, whereas your "-ls" showed only a single 1GB file inside /data/unsorted-data. I don't think it was ultimately relevant to the problem you ran into though, since the `sort` and `testmapredsort` are both able to work just fine with a single 1GB unsorted-data. I ended up just manually deleting the extra unsorted-data files when reproducing the problem.

Comment: Also, I should mention, it wasn't absolutely necessary to delete those extra files in order to reproduce the problem; it would have still happened if there were multiple unsorted files. It just made the repro happen faster since I only needed to wait for 1GB instead of, say, 10GB worth of sorting. Also, the reason yours only had 1 file could just be due to any number of default settings combined with the sizes of your machines, amount of memory available, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the change in keys from `test.randomwrite.bytes_per_map` and `test.randomwriter.maps_per_host` to `mapreduce.randomwriter.bytespermap` and `mapreduce.randomwriter.mapsperhost` causing the settings to not get through to randomwriter, the core of the problem as indicated by the filenames you listed under `/data/sorted-data` is that your sorted data consists of *map* outputs, whereas correctly sorted output only comes from *reduce* outputs; essentially, your `sort` command is only performing the map portion of the sort, and never performing the merge in a subsequent reduce stage. Because of this, your `testmapredsort` command is correctly reporting that the sort did not work.

Checking the code of [Sort.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/2.2.0-cdh5.0.0-beta-1/org/apache/hadoop/examples/Sort.java#85) you can see that there is in fact no protection against `num_reduces` somehow getting set to 0; the typical behavior of Hadoop MR is that setting the number of reduces to 0 indicates a "map only" job, where the map outputs go directly to HDFS rather than being intermediate outputs passed to reduce tasks. Here are the relevant lines:

```
85     int num_reduces = (int) (cluster.getMaxReduceTasks() * 0.9);
86     String sort_reduces = conf.get(REDUCES_PER_HOST);
87     if (sort_reduces != null) {
88        num_reduces = cluster.getTaskTrackers() * 
89                        Integer.parseInt(sort_reduces);
90     }
```

Now, in a normal setup, all of that logic using "default" settings should provide a nonzero number of reduces, such that the sort works. I was able to repro your problem by running:

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar sort -r 0 /data/unsorted-data /data/sorted-data
```

using the `-r 0` to force 0 reduces. In your case, more likely `cluster.getMaxReduceTasks()` is returning 1 (or possibly even 0 if your cluster is broken). I don't know off the top of my head all the ways that method could return 1; it appears that simply setting `mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` to 1 doesn't apply to that method. Other factors that go into task capacity include numbers of cores and the amount of memory available.

Assuming your cluster is at least capable of 1 reduce task per TaskTracker, you can retry your sort step using `-r 1`:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /data/sorted-data
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar sort -r 1 /data/unsorted-data /data/sorted-data
```