# HDFS benchmarking

Tags: hadoop

i wrote the following command for HDFS Benchmarking

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_PREFIX/hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar TestDFSIO -write nrFiles 5 -fileSize 100
```

it says that "jar file with the following name does not exist"

is it that the following hadoop jar file is not there or is there an other version?

My Hadoop version- HADOOP 2.7.2

Comment: Is `$HADOOP_PREFIX/hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar` where you expect? It needs to be a local jar. Try it without `$HADOOP_PREFIX`, and run from the folder where the jar is.

Comment: how to know where is jar file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317907/where-is-hadoop-test-jar-in-hadoop2